# Mobile Browsers don't display images on website

Tags: image, mobile

Created a website, looks pretty solid on the desktop.  (http://foo.com) Used an .htaccess redirect to send those using mobile browsers to subpage (http://foo.com/m.html).  Redirect is working like a charm.

My problem is that one image (and for that matter, the background color) doesn't display on the mobile page, on any mobile browser.  I've tried reformatting it (.png, .jpg, .gif), resizing it (down to 55p x 44p).  It is the only image on the page.  I've tried using a css stylesheet specifically for the mobile subpage, I've tried not using a stylesheet at all and simply putting the image in the body.  Nothing works.  I've searched for an answer but all I can find is 'why doesn't my wallpaper display on my mobile phone', which doesn't help at all.

Anyway, if someone knows what I'm doing wrong, I'd really appreciate it.  Thanks all!

Comment: If I could see HTML/CSS then who knows..

Comment: Sure...here's the HTML/CSS for the site (HTML first):

Comment: @atlavis Here goes:
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" /><title>Foo</title><link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="mobile.css" type="text/css"></head><body><img src="../images/logo.jpg"></div><div class="gps"><a href="gps.html">GPS</a></div></body></html>

Comment: @atlavis CSS:

body
{ 
background-image:('background.gif');
width: 100%;
height: 100%
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed; 
color:white;
a {color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration: underline; }
a:visited {color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration: underline; }
}

Comment: Edited HTML to remove all divs.  Page displays correctly but image still shows as question mark.

Comment: Reduced image size to 9.2 KB, text (including code) totals 2 KB.  Still not showing.  Mobile site displays correctly on desktop, with image and background showing, still does not display correctly on mobile devices, even after clearing cache, history, and cookies.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem, I've done a very simple page, with a single image inside, surfing there with desktop was all right, while going there with a mobile makes the image invisible, it takes the place, but without display, like with "visibility:hidden";
after some tries, i've noticed that the image was saved in a `CMYK` color space, I've converted the image in `RGB` color space and then all goes right.

mobile browsers seeams to not manage the CMYK image versions...

Answer (score 0):

Look at CSS part:

```
background-image:('background.gif')
```

Do You think all is OK here? Because I think it's not...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-image

Comment: Took care of that (I was editing and cutting & pasting for this), same issue.  The image will show for a few hours, and then when I go and check tomorrow on my mobile devices, it won't show.

Comment: Image displayed last night, now not displaying this morning.

Comment: Maybe it's server-side problem.