# Images won't load in mobile browser (500 error thrown)

Tags: html, asp.net, image, mobile

I have an ASP.NET website running on II 7.5 that I'm trying to make mobile-friendly.  For the most part it's working fine, however, I'm finding that none of my images will load when viewed with a mobile browser.  When I try to view any of the images directly through the URL on a mobile browser, I get an ASP.NET "Access to the path [path] is denied", but the path it references is at a location that doesn't exist in the file system (my website's path followed by "/App_Data/Cache/...").

I've been searching online extensively and tried quite a few resolutions to no avail (such as changing image sizes, setting the max-width on the `img` element to 100%, setting the width and heighth of the `img` tag to the exact width and heighth of the image, using `background-image`, etc).  The error that shows up in Chrome Developer Tools is just 500 Internal Server Error -- I only get the above more-detailed error when I try to access the image directly.

An example of one method I've tried in css using background-image:

```
background-image: url("Images/heroIpad.jpg");
```

The only way I've been able to get images to display on a mobile browser is by converting the image to a base64 encoded string and hence not trying to load the actual image, but I can't do that for larger background images.  The images all display fine on desktop browsers.

Any help provided is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [Mobile Browsers don't display images on website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687733/mobile-browsers-dont-display-images-on-website?rq=1). You can do CMYK to Rgb conversion here [Convert images from CMYK to the RGB color space](http://www.cmyk2rgb.com/) or other options thru Google.